# Content URI and Localization

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an app with a feature where a user can choose a folder to save images in.  The user picks this once and images are saved in the background at a later time without user intervention.

I'm using the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` intent for the user to allow the user to select a folder 
(or other content provider):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
startActivityForResult(intent, DirectoryPickerRequest);
```

This all works fine and I properly get a Uri from the activity result:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == DirectoryPickerRequest) {
            Uri treeUri = data.getData();
            mDirectory.setText(treeUri.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that the Uri returns something like this:
`content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AOutput%2FDirectory`

This is fine, but how do I display this to the user in any sort of localized way?  I'd like the user to be able to confirm the location before hitting Save.  For example, if it's a file I'd like to show them `"The/Output/Directory/They/Selected"` in this case.  My understanding is that it's not necessarily a file so I can't just pretend it's a File and use the file API to get the path.

Is there a generic and localized way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but how do I display this to the user in any sort of localized way?

Wrap that in a `DocumentFile` using `fromTreeUri()`, then call `getName()` on the `DocumentFile`. That will get a "display name". It should be something that the user will recognize.

> For example, if it's a file I'd like to show them "The/Output/Directory/They/Selected" in this case

That is not possible. There is no requirement that this document tree exist on the filesystem in any form or fashion. For example, they could be creating a tree in Google Drive.